# base64encode/decode issues with Blob.toString() method

Tags: apex, platform-event, base64

Why would this work in anonymous apex:

```
String a = '[{\"salesOrder\":{\"externalId\":\"\",\"ebsHeaderId\":\"12345\",\"ebsOrderNumber\":\"12345\",\"orderNumber\":\"12345\",';
String encode = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(a));
System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, encode);

Blob b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encode);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, b.toString());
```

But this doesn't (paraphrasing):

test class code (publishes a platform event):

```
String ebiInvoiceInterfaceTestString = '[{\"salesOrder\":{\"externalId\":\"\",\"ebsHeaderId\":\"12345\",\"ebsOrderNumber\":\"12345\",\"orderNumber\":\"12345\",';
String payloadBlob = 
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(ebiInvoiceInterfaceTestString));
System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, payloadBlob);
ebi.PayloadBody1__c = payloadBlob;
Database.SaveResult sr = EventBus.publish(ebi);`
```

consumer class (after insert helper class):

```
Blob payloadBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(ebi.PayloadBody1__c + ebi.PayloadBody2__c + ebi.PayloadBody3__c);
String payload = payloadBlob.toString();`
```

I keep getting this error:

```
System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because PayloadBody2 and PayloadBody3 are *null*, you end up adding extra junk text to the end of the base64 string, which subsequently fails to decode. Make sure they're not null first:

```
String part1 = ebi.PayloadBody1__c,
       part2 = ebi.PayloadBody2__c,
       part3 = ebi.PayloadBody3__c;
part1 = part1 == null? '': part1;
part2 = part2 == null? '': part2;
part3 = part3 == null? '': part3;
Blob payloadBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(part1+part2+part3);
String payload = payloadBlob.toString();
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for this. I actually just wrote this in right after you commented... I've been burned by nulls in apex before, I should have caught this. Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @NathanLee Yeah, it's a rather unfortunate language feature. I do wish that null strings just magically converted themselves to an empty string instead of the string "null", which is almost never what you want.

Comment: While we're on the subject, are you aware of any limitations around charsets as they relate to platform events? I had to add this into my consumer class because I was getting an error trying to publish a sfpe from Boomi, which sends text fields encoded as UTF-8. I'm able to encode as base64 then decode within SF, so not a huge issue, but still annoying.

Comment: @NathanLee Platform events should use UTF-8 by default. Maybe there was a header that was overriding this behavior? I'm not sure if it'd be in scope to ask here, but I'd be interested in seeing a question about it (we can at least look in to it).

Comment: for sure. I created a SF case around it to get some answers. I'll pose the question in another post and see what happens.